# Making query on Google BigQuery, depending on column specified by Python function output

Tags: python, sql, pandas, google-bigquery

I have a simple HTML page asking a user to type in and submit the name of an animal of their choosing. I then have a python function that converts the entered common name of animal to it's scientific name, and what level of taxonomy it was able to convert to.

For example: Panda -> Ailuropoda melanoleuca, species

I need help with the next step, which is taking the output of this first python function, and making a query into a pandas dataframe on Google's BigQuery. Below is a screenshot of the table's preview.

[image]

Below here is the snippet off my main.py that inlcudes the query-making function, and the function calls at the bottom:

```
def make_query(taxon, level):
    project_id = "sentinel-system"

    data_frame = pandas_gbq.read_gbq(
        "SELECT * FROM `animal_database.gbif_occurrence` WHERE species=%s LIMIT 10, (taxon)",
        project_id=project_id,
        index_col=level)

    number_of_images = len(data_frame.index)

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        'Sentinel System-a6746634aad2.json')
    pandas_gbq.context.credentials = credentials
    pandas_gbq.context.project = 'sentinel-system'

    if occurrences > 0:
        print('We found %d images of the animal you searched for!' %(number_of_images))
    else:
        print('Sorry, we couldn''t find any images of the animal you searched for.')
    return 0

taxonomy, level = (common_to_sci('Panda'))
name = taxonomy[-1, -1]
print(name)
print(level)

submission_check = (make_query(name, level))
```

The issue with this function is two-fold. First, the smaller issue is that running main.py currently shows the error

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Syntax error: Illegal input character "%" at [1:63]
```

Where using a python tuple argument is a solution I learned from [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/discussion/70461/thread/28342216/?limit=25), and I'm not sure what this SQL query should look like.

The second, more general issue is, I understand the SQL query needs to reference exactly the same string as is used in a column heading in my BigQuery table. But what if the taxonomy level was not 'species' and was instead 'genus/family/order'? Is there a way to make the SQL query more generalized for cases when 'level' != 'species'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trial and error using @itroulli's answer, reading [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration#query-config) they linked, and general tweaking, this was the solution that worked for me.

```
project_id = "sentinel-system"

table = 'animal_database.gbif_occurrence'

query = 'SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {}=\'{}\''.format(table, level, taxon)

data_frame = pandas_gbq.read_gbq(query, project_id=project_id)
```

Working with the given table, the SQL query searches for the correct column to search through (given by 'level') and under that column, reads for an animal's scientific name given by 'taxon.'

Answer (score 0):

According to the [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration#query-config) regarding `pandas_gbq`, you should use a separate config variable for parameterized queries:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM `animal_database.gbif_occurrence` WHERE @species=@taxonomy LIMIT 10"

query_config = {
'query': {
    'parameterMode': 'NAMED',
    'queryParameters': [
        {
            'name': 'species',
            'parameterType': {'type': 'STRING'},
            'parameterValue': {'value': level}
        },
        {
            'name': 'taxonomy',
            'parameterType': {'type': 'STRING'},
            'parameterValue': {'value': taxon}
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, is the first { } indicating the column of the table to look into and the second { } indicating the specific name to look for (and count occurrences of)?

Comment: Hi @itroulli, after following your advice, I'm still getting a similar error ```pandas_gbq.gbq.GenericGBQException: Reason: 400 Syntax error: Unexpected "{" at [1:55]```. Is this an issue of using standard SQL instead of Legacy SQL, or something else I'm missing? Cheers

Comment: Indeed, I was mistaken. I edited my answer following the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, this is certainly getting me closer to where I need to be, but am still a little confused on the parameters @species=@taxonomy. 


Since 'species' is choosing which column title to look through by getting it's value from what 'level' is (either species, genus, family, or order) and 'taxonomy' is getting the scientific name of the animal from 'taxon,' is '@species=@taxonomy' implying 'look in "level" column for "taxon" animal name'? 


At the moment, running a query is downloading zero rows from the BigQuery table where there should be at least one entry

Comment: Hi @itroulli, I found a different workaround that did the trick for me. I'm sure I didn't get your solution working out of my own inexperience with SQL, and I appreciate your help with this. I'll post my solution in a new answer